# Highlighting potential position of dynamic control in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created application where user can drag and drop the controls during run-time. I use my `ss` function to align the controls in a table like fashion using 2D-array. I want the application to show/highlight the position where the control will be placed when its brought near certain coordinate.

```
struct IconPanel
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
}

static void ss(Control control)
{
    int row, col, nearestCol = 0, nearestRow = 0, rowDist = 100, diff, colDist = 100;

    for (row = 0; row < iconPanels.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (col = 0; col < iconPanels.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            diff = Math.Abs(control.Left - iconPanels[row, col].left);
            if (diff < colDist)
            {
                colDist = diff;
                nearestCol = col;
            }
            diff = Math.Abs(control.Top - iconPanels[row, col].top);
            if (diff < rowDist)
            {
                rowDist = diff;
                nearestRow = row;
            }
        }
    }
    control.Left = iconPanels[nearestRow, nearestCol].left;
    control.Top = iconPanels[nearestRow, nearestCol].top;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably **don't** want these position markers to persist, so this is one of the **rare** cases where I would use

```
using ( Graphics G = theParentContainer.CreateGraphics()) 
       foreach(Rectangle rect in yourPositions) G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect);
```

Clean them up after the drop or after leaving the control etc.. by calling `theParentContainer.Invalidate();`

This assumes that you know the possible position and can create a

```
List<Rectangle> yourPositions = new List<Rectangle>();
```

holding them.

As we all know ;-) graphics created with a `Graphics` object that was instantiated with `Control.CeateGraphics` won't persist and will dissappear with the next `Paint` event. But for such an **interactive** helper graphics this is perfect. Other examples are rubberband-drawing or cursor tracking..

Comment: I only want the space where control might be placed after ss function is executed. I know the position in which the control will be placed using iconPanels[nearestRow, nearestCol].left,top. However i am not able to assign that position to the rectangle since rectangle.left cant be set. if i could specify the position for the created rectangle it would be perfect.

Comment: `Rectangle` is a structure and to set the left side you simply(?) create a fresh one with e.g. `new Rectangle(location, size);`

Answer (score 0):

On control that you would like to be highlited subscribe to `Paint` event.

```
private void highlightControl_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) {

    if(mouse is over or other control is over) { 
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
    }       
}
```